# Creating a virtual template method in Java

Tags: java, templates, virtual, resultset

The situation I'm trying to create is the following:

I have a base class containing a static template method that receives a `ResultSet` filled by a query in the database, and returns a list with the proper results.

I have some classes, that derive from the one cited above, that represents each table from the database and all of them have a constructor that receives the `ResultSet` and builds the object.

The code I've written is:

```
public class TableBase 
{
    public static <T extends TableBase> List<T> getResults(ResultSet p_Rs) throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        List<T> v_Table = new ArrayList<T>();
        T v_TB = null;
        while(p_Rs.next())
            v_Table.add(new T(p_Rs));
        return v_Table;
    }
}
```

The error I got is: `Cannot instantiate the type T`.

It is clear to me that it would be necessary for the compiler to "know" that all the child classes would implement the constructor that receives the `ResultSet` variable, but I can't create a "abstract constructor".

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve that?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You have to pass the function some object that knows about `T`. Perhaps some sort of factory object

Answer (score 2):

You can not instantiate generic Types.

You can use either Factory

```
 public static <T extends TableBase> List<T> getResults
 (ResultSet p_Rs, Factory<T> factory)

//Create instance using factory
```

Or  Class as type.

```
public static <T extends TableBase> List<T> getResults
(ResultSet p_Rs, Class<T> type)
//type.newInstance()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You must tell the runtime exactly type.

Maybe you  can do like this：

1. `TableBase` must have a default constructor.
2. `TableBase` must have a setResultSet method.

   ```
   public class TableBase {
     public static <T extends TableBase> List<T> getResults(ResultSet p_Rs, Class<T> clazz)
           throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
       List<T> v_Table = new ArrayList<T>();
       T v_TB = clazz.newInstance();
       while (p_Rs.next())
           v_TB.setResultSet(p_Rs);
       v_Table.add(v_TB);
       return v_Table;
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflect, something like:

```
while(p_Rs.next())
        v_Table.add(newInstance(T, p_Rs));


public <T extends TableBase> T newInstance(T t, ResultSet p_Rs){
       try {
            Constructor constructor = t.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(ResultSet.class); 
            return (T)constructor.newInstance(p_Rs);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } 

}
```